# how do I get the raw field values in a twig?

Tags: drupal, twig

In Drupal 9, I have created a field[description] which is a List in a content type[country]. In the description list, I added two values like name, capital as dropdown. Here is the condition:

```
if(description==name) { //country name should be displayed) }
if(description==capital) { //the capital name should be displayed }
```

How do I do this using twig?

I haven't tried coz I had no idea. Can anyone give me solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the twig code.

```
    {% if country.field_description.value == 'name' %}
      {{ country.title.value }}
    {% elseif country.field_description.value == 'capital' %}
      {{ country.field_capital.value }}
    {% endif %}
```